# A problem of a sequence and its sum

Tags: combinatorics, integer-sequence

{a(n)} is such a sequence, satisfying,

1. For all a(i) ∈ {a(n)}, a(i) =1 or -1
2. Let S(j) = Sum[a(i) , {i ,1, j}], then for all 1<=j<=n ,S(j)>=0.

For a given n , how many {a(n)} are there?

Comment: Do you want to solve this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M. Both by a pencil and mma, especially the latter, for here is the site of mma.

Answer (score 1):

From Sloane's [A001405](https://oeis.org/A001405) and [A210736](https://oeis.org/A210736), your sequence `a[n]` is the number of length `n` words on {-1,1} such that the sum of any of its prefixes is always nonnegative. The count given there is written in Mathematica as follows.

```
Binomial[n,Floor[n/2]]
```

For example,

```
Table[Binomial[n,Floor[n/2]],{n,1,10}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 35, 70, 126, 252}

One, far less efficient, way to generate and count the sequences uses the following functions.

```
u[v_?MatrixQ] := Map[And @@ NonNegative[#] &, v]
w[n_] := Pick[#, u[#]] &[Map[Accumulate, Tuples[{1, -1}, n]]]

Table[Length[w[n]],{n,1,10}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 35, 70, 126, 252}

Comment: It's better to use `Quotient[n, 2]` than `Floor[n/2]`.